# How to perform page load for page with API in it?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing, jmeter-plugins, rest-api

I have tried RESTAPI testing for few projects, but I have a task now to perform concurrency testing/ load test of a page.

When I inspect the page load in chrome >> Network tab, it shows one Index page and rest are APIs. After creating the script when I ran the script. Index page is showing 200 response code but shows a message: Javascript not enabled for your browser.

For other APIs, I am getting proper json output. I am using Jmeter tool.

Please suggest how do I proceed with load testing.

Comment: Do you want to render the page and investigate the performance of the UI or are we talking about solely the services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you will need to create a relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler either manually or using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and execute this request after the main request.

If there are more requests in scope, i.e. your application is built using [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) technology you might want to execute these requests in parallel to exactly mimic the real browser behaviour, it can be achieved using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/). Parallel controller is a JMeter Plugin, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)